# nginx timeout not working in the http streaming

Tags: nginx

I am running a ollama server which runs a llama2 on the cloud server.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:11434/api/generate -d '{
>   "model": "llama2",
>   "prompt":"Why is the sky blue?"
> }'
```

the result is starting to stream in 3 seconds

```
{"model":"llama2","created_at":"2023-09-01T22:35:43.271181437Z","response":" The","done":false}
....
....
```

However, for the public visit there is a nginx server connecting to this ollama server, but everytime visiting the service in public IP always causes 504 timeout.

the configuration of nginx server timeout doesn't work.

```
server {
        listen 9003;
        server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

                proxy_read_timeout 150000;
                proxy_connect_timeout 150000;
                proxy_send_timeout 150000;
     }
}
```

usually timeout 150000 should be enough to solve the timeout issue since ollama inference is only within 3 seconds.

how would I configure nginx in the correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

investigate more on 'event-stream',

```
 header:{
  'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream'
}
```

therefore

1. http version 1.1 supports long connection

   proxy_http_version 1.1
2. make header to be event stream

   ```
   proxy_set_header Connection 'keep-alive';
   proxy_set_header Cache-Control 'no-cache';
   proxy_set_header Content-Type 'text/event-stream';
   ```
3. disable the buffering to make sure the real time connection

   proxy_buffering off;